# in DrRacket, DrJava, DrPython, what does "Dr" stand for?

Tags: racket, drjava

Currently there are some IDEs for some programming languages like DrRacket (DrScheme), DrJava and DrPython. Anyone knows What does the prefix "Dr" stand for?

Comment: The trend began with PLT Scheme. The Scheme interpreter/compiler was called MzScheme, the ("vanilla") editor was called MrEd, the friendly editor DrRacket and so on. The idea behind DrRacket caught on, and a team subsequently tried to mimick DrRacket in Java and later in Python. (To be clear: Pronouncs Mz as Miss, Dr as Doctor and Mr as Mister)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means Doctor. The idea is that the IDE is some sort of doctor/professor about a language.

Comment: This hypothesis is supported by [the DrJava paper](http://drjava.org/papers/drjava-paper.shtml), titled "DrJava: A lightweight pedagogic environment for Java"